# Optional comment sections in Ada function header

Tags: function, header, comments, ada

When a reader starts to read the function code, he should already have a very good idea of what it is does, how it does it, and what problems he might meet. I'm trying to write clean, structured, well-commented code that is easy to understand. And I'm reading Ada Style Guide and some things I didn't understand well enough, **what can i write for optional sections** (for exapmle: `@Error_Handling, @Pre, @Post`).
I want to represent this Function like an example. Using the above guidelines, a standard function header may be derived:

```
--  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  @Function: Arithmetic_Mean
--
--  @Description:
--    Function to find the mean of a numeric vector. The program should
--    work on a zero-length vector (with an answer of 0.0).
--  @Usage: (opt)
--  @Parameter:
--    +Num: Given array
--  @Return: Averages/Arithmetic mean or zero
--  @Error_Handling: (opt)
--  @Pre: (opt)
--  @Post (opt)
type Mean_Numbers is array (Natural range <>) of Float;
function Arithmetic_Mean (Num : Mean_Numbers) return Float is
   Sum : Float := 0.0;
begin
   if Num'Length > 0 then
      while Num'First <= Num'Last loop
         Sum := Sum + Num(Num'First );
      end loop;
      return Sum / Float (Num'Length);
   end if;
   return 0.0;
end Arithmetic_Mean;
```

And here is another example:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------- ... --
--  @Function: Get_Index
--  @Description:
--     Returns the minimum index of Item in A.
--  @Parameters:
--     +A: the array
--     +Item: element searched for
--  @Return:
--     The minimum index of Item in A.
--  @Pre:
--    true
--  @Post:
--     if exists 1 <= I <= UPPER_BOUND: A(I) = Item then
--       result = min {1 <= k <= UPPER_BOUND | a(j) = item }
--    else
--       result = 0
```

Comment: I don't really see a question here. You can include in an (optional) header whatever (optional) sections you or your employer see fit.

Comment: Error handling refers to the anticipation, detection, and resolution of programming, application, and communications errors. The precondition and postcondition constitute the contract of the function. So:
The precondition is the promise that you make before running a bit of code;
The postcondition is the promise that the code makes after it’s been run. But it seems to me not really clear what exactly should I write?

Comment: There's *no Ada question* in your question.  "What can I write for optional sections"? Anything you want.

Comment: I also think like you, but my professor didn't thinks so. He has been asked the following question:
The `Mean (A : in Integer_Array_Type) return Integer` calculates and returns the arithmetic mean of the input array. The type `Integer_Array_Type` is defined as `array (1 .. Upper_bound) of Integer`. **What are the pre and post conditions for this function?** I have another similar questions...

Comment: This is a software engineering question, figuring out the answer to which is your assignment. Use your textbook(s) and lecture notes. That it's being supplied in an Ada syntax is incidental to the question, it's equally applicable to most any programming language.

Comment: I don’t recognise the language that `@Post` is written in in your second example, so I can’t tell whether it’s correct or not. Perhaps it would be better in English? Though (disagreeing with your professor, so disregard as you please!) I would prefer `@Description` to be improved instead of having `@Post` (and leave out `@Return`, repetitive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Pre` and `@Post` tags should document your module's approach to [*Design by Contract*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). As you observed, any [precondition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition) must be true  for successful execution, and any [postcondition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition) is a promise to be fulfilled by your code. The `@Error_Handling` tag identifies how you deal with violations of the other two.

As a concrete example, your implementation of `Arithmetic_Mean` silently ignores an empty input array, returning a mean of zero; it propagates any exceptions that are raised. These are the behaviors that should be documented.

Several benefits accrue:

1. The API programmer can clearly state the intended behavior.
2. The API client can distinguish among possible sources of error.
3. A reviewer can verify whether the intention matches the implementation.

See also [*Introduction to Ada: Design by contracts*](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/contracts.html), which illustrates Ada 2012 support for enforcing contracts. The [*Rationale for Ada 2012*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-TOC.html) offers an [overview](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-1-3-1.html) of the topic and [related aspects](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-2.html).

Comment: Actually, the implementation of `Arithmetic_Mean` loops forever! the `while` loop ought to be `for J in Num’Range loop Sum := Sum + Num (J); end loop;`.